# Add 3 columns to DataFrame via map

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is it possible to add 3 new columns to this little DataFrame in one map?

```
import datetime as dt  
import pandas as pd
from pandas import *

df = pd.DataFrame({'myDate':['2006-02-12'
                             ,'2007-07-20'
                             ,'2009-05-19']})

def convert_date(val):    
    d, m, y = val.split('-')
    return int(d), int(y), int(m)

df[['day', 'year','month']] = df.myDate.map(convert_date)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can convert column `myDate` [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and then use [`dt.year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.year.html), [`dt.month`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.month.html) and [`dt.day`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.day.html):

```
df['myDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df.myDate)

df['year'] = df.myDate.dt.year
df['month'] = df.myDate.dt.month
df['day'] = df.myDate.dt.day

print (df)
     myDate  year  month  day
0 2006-02-12  2006      2   12
1 2007-07-20  2007      7   20
2 2009-05-19  2009      5   19
```

If want use your approach, you need add `pd.Series`, because else you return `tuples`. And change `map` to `apply`:

```
def convert_date(val):    
    d, m, y = val.split('-')
    return pd.Series([int(d), int(y), int(m)])

df[['day', 'year','month']] = df.myDate.apply(convert_date)

print (df)
       myDate   day  year  month
0  2006-02-12  2006    12      2
1  2007-07-20  2007    20      7
2  2009-05-19  2009    19      5
```

I try use `map`, but result is:

```
def convert_date(val):    
    d, m, y = val.split('-')
    return int(d), int(y), int(m)

df['a'], df['b'], df['c'] = df.myDate.map(convert_date)
print (df)
       myDate     a     b     c
0  2006-02-12  2006  2007  2009
1  2007-07-20    12    20    19
2  2009-05-19     2     7     5
```

Comment: thanks - why is my current approach not working? Are you able to correct it?

Answer (score 2):

you can use [.str.split()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html#pandas.Series.str.split):

```
In [11]: df[['day', 'year','month']] = df.myDate.str.split('-', expand=True).astype(int)

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
       myDate   day  year  month
0  2006-02-12  2006     2     12
1  2007-07-20  2007     7     20
2  2009-05-19  2009     5     19
```

or using [.str.extract()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html)

```
In [21]: df.myDate.str.extract(r'(?P<year>\d{4})-(?P<month>\d{2})-(?P<day>\d{2})', expand=True).astype(int)
Out[21]:
   year  month  day
0  2006      2   12
1  2007      7   20
2  2009      5   19
```

Comment: Thanks - why is the  approach I'm taking not working?

Comment: Don't do it the way, you want it to do! It'll be slower, compared to vectorized approach and it won't look ideomatic

Comment: Thanks MaxU - I'd like to use map.